# Simple ruby: adding strings / results from get?

Tags: ruby, string

Getting the full name

```
puts 'Hello there, and what\'s your name?'
name= gets.chomp
puts 'Your first name is ' + name + '? What a lovely name!'
puts 'Whats your second name?'
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Your second name is ' + name + '.'
puts 'So whats your last name?'
name = gets.chomp
puts 'So your last name is: ' + name + '.'
```

I cant seem to get the full name at the end.

```
puts ' Your full name is :' name + name +name '.'
```

^ This seems wrong even when i tried it.

Do i have to create a variable after each name is imputed?

Comment: +1.  Welcome to SO and to ruby.  Please don't be discouraged by the down-votes.  You're question is reasonable for someone new to programming.  You might want to read [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are having trouble with the concept of a variable.

A variable is a position in memory, used to store some kind of data. You refer to the data by using the variable's name. Think of it as a box with a label. For the sake of simplicity, assume you can put a single thing in the box.

When you enter the line `name = gets.chomp`, what your are doing is basically saying "store this information the user will enter in a box, and label that box `name`."

The box is a position in memory. The label is how you find it and retrieve the stored value.

Then, when you write `name = gets.chomp` for the second time, you are doing pretty much the same thing. You store the information the user enters (his second name) in the box labeled `name`. However, you didn't just add this information to the box. You **replaced** the old data.

Then, when you try to get the full name in puts `Your full name is :' name + name +name '.'` you are actually getting the same value from the same "box" three times.

So, what you need is three different "boxes", or in programming vocabulary, three variables. If you use a different variable for each name portion, you will get something like the code below:

```
puts 'Hello there, and what\'s your name?'
first_name = gets.chomp
puts 'Your first name is ' + first_name + '? What a lovely name!'
puts 'Whats your second name?'
second_name = gets.chomp
puts 'Your second name is ' + second_name + '.'
puts 'So whats your last name?'
last_name = gets.chomp
puts 'So your last name is: ' + last_name + '.'    
puts ' Your full name is :' + first_name + second_name + last_name + '.'
```

There are ways to put more complex things inside variables. Like collections of things, instead of single things. You will get to that soon.